# How can native library methods be used in a web application?

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, c

I have many native libraries with a C API that contain functionality I want to use in a web app. What choices are out there (frameworks/languages) for doing this?

Comment: this might help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14180/Using-Unmanaged-C-Libraries-DLLs-in-NET-Applicatio

Comment: What kind of functionality are you talking about? And *where* do you want to use it. (On the server? On the client?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yea i am intersted in both way if possible.?!!

Comment: if you are using jsp at server side then might call c api through jni interface...i am not sure about this..!

Comment: You're going to have to be far more specific before this can be answered.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, there are additional challenges with IIS running web apps that use native DLLs, like what path(s) does it use to find native DLLs for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call native C functions from C#, including ASP.Net, use P/Invoke. It exists for exactly that purpose.

Tutorial Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=VS.71).aspx